# I want to join two dataframes on multiple keys and append the second dataframe to the suitable rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes including NBA statistics from all teams from 2009 to 2019 (30 teams * 10 seasons = 300 rows). I want to join them by adding the columns from the second df to the suitable team_stat_by_season row.

The keys that uniquely fit them to the rows are "TEAM" and "MIN".
That´s what the two df´s look like (in a much shortened way):

```
df1:
Team                 MIN        PTS         FGM
Orlando Magic       48.1        102.8       36.6
Phoenix Suns        48.5        102.1       38.1
Indiana Pacers      48.1        100.8       36.8
Orlando Magic       48.4        103.5       37.5

df2:
Team                 MIN        AST%        REB%
Phoenix Suns        48.5        1.61        52.9
Orlando Magic       48.1        1.54        49.8
Orlando Magic       48.4        1.70        50.6
Indiana Pacers      48.1        1.81        50.9
```

The result should look like:

```
Team                 MIN        PTS          FGM        AST%        REB%
Orlando Magic       48.1        102.8       36.6        1.54        49.8
Phoenix Suns        48.5        102.1       38.1        1.61        52.9    
Indiana Pacers      48.1        100.8       36.8        1.81        50.9
Orlando Magic       48.4        103.5       37.5        1.70        50.6
```

I tried it with the following code:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2, how='left', left_on=['TEAM','MIN'], right_on=['TEAM','MIN'])
```

But unfortunately in the result it always returns NaN in some parts (although I already checked fr the datatypes and they all fit perfectly):

```
Team                 MIN        PTS         FGM         AST%        REB%
Orlando Magic       48.1        102.8       36.6        NaN         NaN
Phoenix Suns        48.5        102.1       38.1        NaN         NaN 
Indiana Pacers      48.1        100.8       36.8        NaN         NaN
Orlando Magic       48.4        103.5       37.5        NaN         NaN
```

I hope someone can help me on that issue and I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `on` instead of `left_on/right_on `

Comment: Check for whitespaces and differences in uppercase / lowercase in the key columns. Solve them with `df1['Team'].str.strip()` or `df1['Team'].str.upper()` for example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full outer join and this will provide the results you need.

saved this as df2.csv

```
Team,MIN,AST%,REB%
Phoenix Suns,48.5,1.61,52.9
Orlando Magic,48.1,1.54,49.8
Orlando Magic,48.4,1.70,50.6
Indiana Pacers,48.1,1.81,50.9
```

saved this one as df1.csv

```
Team,MIN,PTS,FGM
Orlando Magic,48.1,102.8,36.6
Phoenix Suns,48.5,102.1,38.1
Indiana Pacers,48.1,100.8,36.8
Orlando Magic,48.4,103.5,37.5
```

Below is the code

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['Team','MIN'])
```

And below is the output.

```
             Team   MIN    PTS   FGM  AST%  REB%
0   Orlando Magic  48.1  102.8  36.6  1.54  49.8
1    Phoenix Suns  48.5  102.1  38.1  1.61  52.9
2  Indiana Pacers  48.1  100.8  36.8  1.81  50.9
3   Orlando Magic  48.4  103.5  37.5  1.70  50.6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But if I use the outer join it comes out like that:

Comment: `Team                      MIN        PTS         FGM     AST%    REB%   <br/>
Orlando Magic       48.1        102.8       36.6      NaN       NaN  
Phoenix Suns        48.5        102.1       38.1      NaN       NaN  
Indiana Pacers      48.1        100.8       36.8      NaN       NaN  
Orlando Magic       48.4        103.5       37.5      NaN       NaN  
Phoenix Suns        48.5        NaN         NaN      1.61        52.9  
Orlando Magic       48.1        NaN         NaN      1.54        49.8  
Orlando Magic       48.4        NaN         NaN      1.70        50.6  
`

Comment: I'm sorry, I just joined stackoverflow and I don't kno how to display the dataframe above in the comment section.. But the problem is that the rows of df2 are attached at the bottom of df1. But what I am looking for is to attach each row of df2 at the end of the suitable row, so that the number of rows of the joined df is the same as df1. 
Can you help me with that? Thanks so much by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Almost there :) You need to be consistent in how you spell "Team": it's all uppercase in your dataframe, but not in your join.

With the following

```
pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2, how='left', on=['Team','MIN'])
```

you will get

```
    Team    MIN     PTS     FGM     AST%    REB%
0   Magic   48.1    102.8   36.6    1.54    49.8
1   Suns    48.5    102.1   38.1    1.61    52.9
2   Pacers  48.1    100.8   36.8    1.81    50.9
3   Magic   48.4    103.5   37.5    1.70    50.6
```